# jQuery timeout change div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a bunch of divs like so

```
<div class="listingImage">
    <div style="background-image:url('listings/listing1/1/image8Main.jpeg')"></div>
    <div style="background-image:url('listings/listing1/1/image2.jpeg')"></div>
    <div style="background-image:url('listings/listing1/1/image3.jpeg')"></div>
    <div style="background-image:url('listings/listing1/1/image4.jpeg')"></div>
    <div style="background-image:url('listings/listing1/1/image5.jpeg')"></div>
    <div style="background-image:url('listings/listing1/1/image6.jpeg')"></div>
    <div style="background-image:url('listings/listing1/1/image7.jpeg')"></div>
    <div style="background-image:url('listings/listing1/1/image9.jpeg')"></div>
</div>
```

With css:

```
.listingImage>div: {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:98;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    background:50% 50%/cover;
}
.listingImage>div.active {
    z-index:99;
}
```

I have a jQuery script to cycle through these divs and change the z-index to put one on top of all the rest.

```
<script>
    var timer
    $(".listingImage").on("mouseenter", function() {
        var element = $(this)
        timer = window.setTimeout(function() {
            if (element.children(".active").length) {
                element.children(".active").removeClass("active").next().addClass("active")
            } else {
                element.children().first().addClass("active")
            }
        }, 500)
    })
    $(".listingImage").on("mouseleave", function() {
        $(".active", this).removeClass("active")
        clearTimeout(timer)
    })
</script>
```

This script will go to next div and stop working. I believe I have two problems. It might have something to do with `var element=$(this)`. Also, my mouseleave is being triggered by changes in z-index. How can I achieve cycling through divs and then returning to normal onmouseleave?

Task, on mouseenter, start cycle through boxes. On mouseleave, end cycle and restart. https://jsfiddle.net/sy5br7d0/

Comment: A jsfiddle or equivalent would be helpful

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Why are you binding the timer to "mouseenter" if you want it to cycle automatically? Please clarify, and also properly indent and space out your code.

Comment: @sjm I added jsfiddle. So it goes to box1, but doesn't continue to next box. To second question: because when you enter the box, you cycle through images. When you leave the box, timer is cleared and cycle stops and resets to original box.

Comment: you want to show all div in cycle one after the another  when you hover or mouseenter right ?

Comment: Yes, one by one change to "active" class to put on top. On mouse out of parent, revert to normal and clear all active classes

Comment: Just use `setInterval` and `clearInterval` instead of `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout`. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sy5br7d0/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to cycle through all the div's then u should use **timer =  window.setInterval** rather than using **window.setTimeout**.

moidified script:

```
<script>
var timer
    $(".listingImage").on("mouseenter", function() {
        var element = $(this)
        timer = window.setInterval(function() {
            if (element.children(".active").length) {
                element.children(".active").removeClass("active").next().addClass("active")
            } else {
                element.children().first().addClass("active")
            }
        }, 500)
    })
    $(".listingImage").on("mouseleave", function() {
        $(".active", this).removeClass("active")
        clearTimeout(timer)
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

User `setInterval()` instead of `setTimeout()`

```
var timer
$(".listingImage").on("mouseenter", function () {
    var element = $(this)
    timer = window.setInterval(function () {
        if (element.children(".active").length>0) {
      element.children(".active").removeClass("active").next().addClass("active")
        } else {
            element.children().first().addClass("active")
        }
    }, 500)
})
$(".listingImage").on("mouseleave", function () {
    $(".active", this).removeClass("active")
    clearInterval(timer)
})
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sy5br7d0/2/)